# Using OpenVPN with systemd

Tags: debian, configuration, systemd, openvpn

Ok, so I've been searching the web for solutions to this problem with no answers seeming to work for me.  Hopefully someone can help me.  I'm only trying to configure the OpenVPN Client.

I'm running `CrunchBang Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and I just switched over to using `systemd`.  The changeover went smooth enough but now I can't get my OpenVPN client to come up using systemd  I've tried following these configuration tutorials, but nothing works.

- http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Openvpn
- http://d.stavrovski.net/blog/how-to-install-and-set-up-openvpn-in-debian-7-wheezy
- And looked at a bunch of other different guides.

I can bring up the tunnel from the command line with `openvpn /etc/openvpn/vpn.conf`.  So I know the config file is good, it was working with sysvinit just fine so I'm not surprised.  I then attempt to just do a status with `systemctl status openvpn@vpn.service` resulting in:

```
$ sudo systemctl status openvpn@vpn.service
  openvpn@vpn.service
Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

I realized that I need to do some setup for services.  I want to be prompted for a password so I followed this guide to create an `openvpn@.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/`.  But restarting the OpenVPN service still doesn't prompt for a password.

```
$ sudo service openvpn restart
[ ok ] Restarting openvpn (via systemctl): openvpn.service.
```

The Fedora tutorials go through the steps of creating symbolic links, but don't create any of the .service files in the walk-throughs.

What piece am I missing?  Do I need to create an openvpn@vpn.service?  If so, where exactly do I place it?  I feel like it shouldn't be this difficult, but I can't seem to find any solution that works for me.  I'm happy to provide any more information that's needed.

### Solution

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   319 Aug  7 10:42 openvpn@.service

[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN connection to %i
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-%i --status /run/openvpn/%i.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/%i.conf
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
WorkingDirectory=/etc/openvpn

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
openvpn@.service (END)
```

Symlink:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   36 Aug  7 10:47 openvpn@vpn.service -> /lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service
```

### **Prompt For Password**

Everything is working now, except for being prompted for a password to connect.  I've attempted [this solution](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=150440).  I tweaked the file from above just a bit, and added an [Expect script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) like in the example.  Working like a charm!  My files are below.

Modified lines from the above `/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service`

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-%i --status /run/openvpn/%i.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --management localhost 5559 --management-query-passwords --management-forget-disconnect --config /etc/openvpn/%i.conf
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/expect /lib/systemd/system/openvpn_pw.exp
```

Expect script `/lib/systemd/system/openvpn_pw.exp`.  Make sure to do the following:

- `chmod +x` on the script.
- Have `telnet` installed

Code of the expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set pass [exec /bin/systemd-ask-password "Please insert Private Key password: "]

spawn telnet 127.0.0.1 5559
expect "Enter Private Key Password:"
send "password 'Private Key' $pass\r"
expect "SUCCESS: 'Private Key' password entered, but not yet verified"
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

**It should be noted that the above solution does log your password entered in plaintext in the following logs in `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/daemon.log`**

Comment: How does the `openvpn@.service` file looks like?

Comment: Updated the post with the current error

Comment: Look in /var/log/{syslog,daemon.log} and `journalctl -b -m` to find why OpenVPN exited. One of those places should contain the real error messages. (Or even `journalctl -b -m _EXE=/usr/sbin/openvpn` should give just OpenVPN messages).

Comment: Yep, I was getting there.  We're hitting the password problem.  I'll try this solution for it: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=150440  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: just for the record: copying the systemd script under /etc/systemd/system makes the changes permanent. If you change the script directly under /lib/systemd/system, this is going to be overwritten at some point by a package update.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the Debian OpenVPN setup with systemd is currently a tad bit broken. To get it to work on my machines I had to:

1. Create `/etc/systemd/system/openvpn@.service.d` (the directory), and place in it a new file with this:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Requires=networking.service
   After=networking.service
   ```

   I called my file `local-after-ifup.conf`. It needs to end with `.conf`. (This is the bit that's currently a tad bit broken.)
2. Create a file in `/etc/tmpfiles.d` (I called mine `local-openvpn.conf`) with the contents:

   ```
   # Type Path         Mode UID  GID  Age Argument
   d      /run/openvpn 0755 root root  -  -
   ```

   This is [Debian bug 741938](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=741938) (fixed in 2.3.3-1).
3. Create a symlink into `multi-user.target.wants` (easiest way is `systemctl enable openvpn@CONF_NAME.service`) E.g., if you have `/etc/openvpn/foo.conf`, you'd use `openvpn@foo.service`.
4. If you also have the SysV init script showing up in systemd, disable it. This is [Debian bug 700888](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=700888) (fixed in 2.3.3-1).

NOTE: 2.3.3-1 or later is [not yet in testing](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/openvpn), though it is in unstable.

Comment: systemctl enable still fails saying no such file or directory.  I don't see any sysv init scripts in /lib/systemd, unless its systemd-initctl?

Comment: @raz The SysV script would be `/etc/init.d/openvpn`; systemd by default runs those just like sysv init would. That's the `openvpn.service` you have; you need to disable it (`systemctl disable`). Does the file `/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service` exist on your system?

Comment: @raz If you have that file, you can try a manual `ln -s /lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/openvpn@vpn.service`

Comment: I don't have that file but I'm sure I could create it.  I disabled the `/etc/init.d/openvpn script.`

Comment: @raz I'm not sure if Crunchbang has a backport of a newer OpenVPN package with it, but if not, you can grab that script from http://sources.debian.net/src/openvpn/2.3.3-1/debian/openvpn%40.service

Comment: @raz Also, I noticed I'd forgotten a step, please see the new number two. Beware that OpenVPN before 2.3.2-8 wasn't compiled with systemd support, so e.g., asking for passwords may not work.

Comment: I did see the update!  I've done everything, updated the post with what I've got file wise.  I have a different error now!

Comment: And yes it is still broken 2 years later.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that explanation. Encountered recently in Debian 9.0 Stretch, fresh install, with its stock OpenVPN 2.4.0. As I found myself facing this issue, I'd actually been trying to wrap my mind around the Systemd "unit scripts" for some time (to hook something I'd normally put in rc.sysinit or rc.local). Apart from solving my OpenVPN vs. Systemd issue, your instructions have explained a lot, pointed me to furter reading and taught me how to configure systemd on my own. I suspect that the maintainer keeps the bug in, to elucidate admins on what Systemd has to offer in Debian.

Comment: I actually have some fond past experience with OpenVPN. I previously compiled my own from source, and had my own approach on how to hook up multiple instances of the OpenVPN service into SysV init (using a mother script that would launch children). I know *exactly* what this (slightly broken) setup in Debian is aiming to achieve, and it is my goal exactly. Now my ages old multi-instance OpenVPN config plays well with the standard Debianese setup of OpenVPN. Kudos, have an upvote :-)

Answer (score 12):

This type of unit file is an Instantiated Service - more details are available [here](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/instances.html)

The following is the unit file for `openvpn` on CentOS 7:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On %I
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
PrivateTmp=true
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/openvpn/%i.pid
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --writepid /var/run/openvpn/%i.pid --cd /etc/openvpn/ --config %i.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and it resides as `/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@service`. The `%i` in the file is replaced with the string after the `@` in the unit name.

As the config file is at `/etc/openvpn/myopenvpn.conf` then the service is started with:

```
systemctl start openvpn@myopenvpn.service
```

Comment: I only have `/usr/lib/systemd/user/`  Nothing else at the `/usr/lib/systemd` level.

Comment: What about `/lib/systemd/system/` ?  I seem to  have both on my system, with identical contents (and they're not symlinks!).

Comment: I just added that file, updated my post with everything.

Answer (score 8):

You need to create the service file by enabling `openvpn@<configuration>.service`.

For example, if the configuration file is `/etc/openvpn/client.conf`, the service name is `openvpn@client.service`.

[From the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenVPN#systemd_service_configuration)

Comment: $ sudo systemctl enable openvpn@vpn.service
[sudo] password for user: 
Failed to issue method call: No such file or directory

Comment: Your configuration file is called 'vpn'?

Comment: Yes, `/etc/openvpn/vpn.conf`

Comment: Does `systemctl start openvpn@vpn.service` not work either? That *should* work...

Comment: $ sudo systemctl start openvpn@vpn.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit openvpn@vpn.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status openvpn@vpn.service' for details.

Comment: The command *should* work so I think there is something wrong with your config. `sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/vpn.conf` ?

Comment: This might help: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/23085/how-to-start-openvpn-service-at-boot-time/

Comment: Added the `sudo openvpn --config line`

Comment: This works for me on Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (Debian Jessie). Thanks!

Comment: this works on bookworm too

Answer (score 8):

1. Place all openvpn *.conf files into `/etc/openvpn/`.
2. Edit `/etc/default/openvpn`. Uncomment this:

   ```
   AUTOSTART="all"
   ```
3. Run `systemctl daemon-reload`.
4. Run `service openvpn start`.

Comment: I think they used this as a solution,  because now is even worse in debian 9, the openvpn does not restart if a error ocurrs that is very stupid... Someone know some solution or workaround, i am writing a script to verify if openvpn is still running!

Comment: This was perfect. it would start and stop even though I called it the obvious `client.conf`, now with this my single config just runs. Thanks!

Comment: _/etc/default/openvpn_ is still there but Debian 10 and its derivatives do not appear to use it - _/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service_ is now a oneshot service that just runs /bin/true (for backwards compatibility?).  The answers stating `systemctl enable openvpn@conffile.service` work.

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution would be, to make use of systemd's `systemd-ask-password`/"[Password Agents](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PasswordAgents/)", which provides a systemd builtin way to funnel passwords/passphrases to services.

You'll need [OpenVPN 2.3.0 or newer](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/commit/9449e6a9eba30c9ed054f57d630a88c9f087080f) to do this.

Comment: This is what the Expect script in my edited post uses.

Comment: Sorry, missed that edit.

Answer (score 1):

The openvpn@.service has evolved greatly between Debians 8 and 9. The original package for Jessie for example fails to `systemctl reload openvpn@`. To fix these the Stretch version introduces 10 new directives in the systemd-file including `PIDFile=` to make reload work again.

For Stretch users, I'd suggest going for the backport, and if not possible to do that, at least get the systemd-file from https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/openvpn and extract `debian/openvpn@.service` into `/etc/systemd/system/openvpn@.service` and enjoy better functionality and security.

Answer (score 0):

On a fresh Jessie_8.0.0 installation I did:

1. copy the old `/etc/openvpn/cluster.conf` (plus `*.key` and `*.crt`) files from wheezy
2. uncommented `AUTOSTART="all"` in `/etc/default/openvpn` - I think this had no effect
3. `/lib/systemd/system-generators/openvpn-generator cluster`
4. `systemctl restart openvpn@cluster.service`

Now the tunnel is up - I will see what will happen after a reboot, but I can't reboot in this moment

Answer (score 0):

I had better luck using `openvpn`'s `--auth-user-pass` option to reference a config file instead of using the `expect` script, i.e.:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-%i --status /run/openvpn/%i.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/%i.conf --auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/credentials.txt
```

where `/etc/openvpn/credentials.txt` is a text file that has my username on line 1 and my password is on line 2.

Obviously if you can't store your credentials in plain text this is not a good solution, but it works for my purposes.