# How to start 2FA-using OpenVPN with systemd?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, openvpn

I have openvpn config that users 2 factor authentication.

If I start it manually, by running:

```
/usr/sbin/openvpn --writepid /run/whatever --cd /etc/openvpn/ --config /etc/openvpn/work.conf
```

it asks for username, then password (provided by software on my phone), and then password for private key. And then it works.

But if/when I try to start it via normal service call:

```
=# service openvpn start work
```

nothing is printed, openvpn doesn't work, and journalctl shows:

```
=# systemctl status openvpn
● openvpn.service - OpenVPN service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since czw 2015-05-28 10:24:22 CEST; 17min ago
  Process: 30395 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 30395 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/openvpn.service

maj 28 10:24:22 krowka systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service...
maj 28 10:41:40 krowka systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN service.
```

Is there anything I could do to make it work "normally", via "service" call, or any other mean, other than manually building /usr/sbin/openvpn invocation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I try to start it via normal service call:
>
> ```
> # service openvpn start work
> ```

No, that's not normal.  That's a quirk of System 5 `rc` toolsets that invokes a System 5 `rc` script with two arguments.  The `rc` script takes the non-standard second argument as the basename of the OpenVPN configuration to use.

This is Ubuntu Linux.  You aren't using System 5 `rc`.  You aren't using its `rc` script.  You are using systemd.  You are using systemd service units, which OpenVPN has in fact had for many years now.  systemd service units aren't scripts and don't *have* script arguments.

What they have are template parameters, and OpenVPN was in fact one of the earlier adopters of the *template units* mechanism when it came along, [having had templatized units since at least 2011](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2011-November/003884.html).  ([Templatized upstart jobs for OpenVPN](https://github.com/jkjuopperi/openvpn-upstart/blob/master/openvpn.conf) have been floating around since at least 2012.)

You're looking at `/lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service`.  What you should be looking at is `/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service`.  Instantiate that on the configuration name:

- `systemctl preset openvpn@work.service`
- `systemctl disable openvpn@work.service`
- `systemctl start openvpn@work.service`
- `systemctl stop openvpn@work.service`
- `systemctl status openvpn@work.service`

Or just let Debian/Ubuntu do the heavy lifting.  There's a *unit generator* in `/lib/systemd/system-generators/openvpn-generator` that automatically instantiates this template against every `*.conf` file in `/etc/openvpn` at bootstrap or when `systemctl daemon-reload` is run.

## Further reading

- [Using OpenVPN with systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148990/)

Comment: Thanks for explanation (even though I don't really appreciate the tone). Too complicated to use. Wrote a simple shell script, and it works just as well. Having to generate "config file for config file" is just plain insane.