# Starting additional OpenVPN connection under systemd

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, openvpn

I have a couple of OpenVPN connections to various servers that are autostarted when I log into my laptop. Other connections, to production servers, have to be set up manually. Until recently I ran Ubuntu 14.04, where I could run things like

```
sudo service openvpn start production-server-21
```

to add a connection. Since upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, and systemd, this no longer works. Is there still a simple way to add a connection or do I have to

```
cd /etc/openvpn
sudo openvpn --config production-server-21.conf &
```

which is much less nice (can't use full path for config file, as it contains relative references to keys/certs).

Comment: [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206490/119298) seems to suggest the equivalent is `sudo systemctl start openvpn@production-server-21.service`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that

```
sudo service openvpn@production-server-21 start
```

works, as well as something similar to what @meuh suggested in their comment:

```
sudo systemctl start openvpn@production-server-21
```