# Starting openvpn client as daemon - in debian

Tags: systemd, openvpn, vpn

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple Openvpn tunnel

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/vpn/config/myclient.ovpn --daemon

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have this service, I can also enable it but starting is not working. status is giving me this:

```
● openvpn.service - Simple Openvpn tunnel
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/openvpn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-12-08 09:24:32 CET; 3s ago
  Process: 29772 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/vpn/config/client-0-130.ovpn --daemon (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 29772 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 08 09:24:32 s20699657 systemd[1]: Started Simple Openvpn tunnel.
Dec 08 09:24:32 s20699657 systemd[1]: openvpn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 08 09:24:32 s20699657 systemd[1]: openvpn.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 08 09:24:32 s20699657 systemd[1]: openvpn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I can't find out what is missing. can someone please look at it? :/

Comment: By far the easiest thing is to start openvpn by executing the start command, *openvpn --config /etc/vpn/config/myclient.ovpn*  (without the daemon option) from the CLI, and study the error message you get. Otherwise *dmesg* or *syslog* might hold some info.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae in cli it works without problem I think the issue is with the `/usr/sbin/openvpn`. in cli, I just do `openvpn --config /etc/vpn/config/myclient.ovpn` and it works

Answer (score 11):

## Use the Debian-supplied mechanism

Don't roll your own service units.  Debian comes with a mechanism for scanning your OpenVPN configuration and making systemd services to match it.  Use that.

Make a `*.conf` file in `/etc/openvpn`.  Debian's/Ubuntu's `/lib/systemd/system-generators/openvpn-generator` will make the service units to match.

Note that newer versions of OpenVPN have split the configuration files directory into `/etc/openvpn/client` and `/etc/openvpn/server`.  This has not (yet) percolated down into a stable version of Debian, although the OpenVPN-supplied `openvpn-client@.service` and `openvpn-server@.service` template units have.

(`openvpn@.service` is a Debian-supplied service unit that works with the Debian-supplied generator.  These are local Debian-made modifications to OpenVPN.  The OpenVPN-supplied service unit templates were developed independently by the OpenVPN people themselves.  They are also better.  If you really want to not use the Debian mechanism, *using these* should be your next stop, before rolling your own service units.)

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206490/5132
- [Starting additional OpenVPN connection under systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296138/)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/378824/5132

Comment: i dont want to start openvpn server, I just need to start the client as daemon. For this I need debian-supplied mechanism?