# OpenVPN doesn't seem to run: active (exited), code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn, syslog

I'm trying to run OpenVPN on Ubuntu remote server. I've been following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial. As of now, I'm right before Step 3, trying to get "VPN 'server' is running" message. However, when I run

```
service openvpn start
service openvpn status
```

I get:

[image]

"active (exited), code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS" response.

i tried checking logs:

```
vim /var/log/syslog
```

But don't see anything suspicious:

[image]

What could be the reasons behind this behaviour?

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/5132

Answer (score 5):

The fact that you are looking at the wrong thing.

Your service is not named `openvpn`.  It is named `openvpn@configuration`.

The instructions that you are following are for an older version of Ubuntu, whose services were arranged differently.  You quite clearly have Ubuntu 15 or later.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/378824/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206490/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/346230/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409689/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451345/5132

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that to start the OpenVPN server on Ubuntu 22, you need to use the following command:

```
systemctl start openvpn-server@server.service
```

The name of the service is based on the name of the configuration file, which, in my case, is located at /etc/openvpn/server/server.conf. For example, if the configuration file is named /etc/openvpn/server/example.conf, then you need to start it with:

```
systemctl start openvpn-server@example.service
```

To find the relevant OpenVPN service files, you can check the /lib/systemd/system directory.

Or, on Ubuntu, you can use `systemctl list-units | grep openvpn` to find the name of the service you need to start.