# Difference between openvpn-client@.service and openvpn@.service?

Tags: systemd, openvpn

I want to run my openvpn as systemd service.
This tutorial tells me to use openvpn@.service template for that:

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Openvpn#Setting_up_a_Linux_OpenVPN_client

```
 ln -s /lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service /etc/systemd/system/openvpn@MyClient.service
```

I can do that but before trying I wonder that in the same folder there is also an openvpn-client@.service file, which is not even mentioned in the tutorial. I looked into both but my knowledge of systemd is limited. From what I can see, both would work running an openvpn client, just openvpn-cliemt@.service would start it with --daemon ovpn-%i. Wouldn't it be better to have it running as a daemon? Is the tutorial just outdated and not covering this .service file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [2.4.0](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/master/Changes.rst), configuration moved to subdirectories: `/etc/openvpn/{client,server}` and the corresponding systemd units were changed from  the generic `openvpn@.service` to `openvpn-client@.service` and `openvpn-server@.service`.

As the changelog describes it:

> OpenVPN now ships with more up-to-date systemd unit files which take
>   advantage of the improved service management as well as some hardening
>   steps. The configuration files are picked up from the
>   /etc/openvpn/server/ and /etc/openvpn/client/ directories (depending
>   on unit file). This also avoids these new unit files and how they work
>   to collide with older pre-existing unit files.

So it appears the Fedora wiki is out-of-date.

Comment: Thanks so I was right using the client version. It works well when I copy the conf into /etc/openvpn/clients

Comment: [Debian is behind, too.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409689/5132)

Comment: @JdeBP Colour me shocked... :p

Comment: And what is the difference between `openvpn@server` and `openvpn-server@server` services? I can see that they both exist when using commands `sudo service openvpn@server status` and  `sudo service openvpn-server@server status`. However only `openvpn-server@server` is used.