# Using openvpn with multiple server under systemd

Tags: systemd, openvpn

Preliminary question: where is stored the default server which is used by the command `systemctl start openvpn` (assume sudo, of course)? It should be in `/etc/default/openvpn`, like it used to be for SysV, but if I change it `systemctl` still connects openvpn to the old server.

Now for the main question.

According to [Using OpenVpn with systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148990/using-openvpn-with-systemd) and also [Correct way of systemd for Openvpn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763583/correct-way-of-systemd-for-openvpn-client-on-16-04-server)  (and other sources) if I have two different servers for my vpn (say, London and Paris) then I need the two config files `/etc/openvpn/London.conf` and `/etc/openvpn/Paris.conf` so that I can start the server of my choice with `systemctl start openvpn@London` or `systemctl start openvpn@Paris`.

Ok, this works.

Now assume I have two different vpn providers (P1 and P2), both with a server in London and one in Paris. One way to set the config files could be

`/etc/openvpn/P1_London.conf`

`/etc/openvpn/P1_Paris.conf`

`/etc/openvpn/P2_London.conf`

`/etc/openvpn/P2_Paris.conf`

and then I should start openvpn accordingly.

What I would like to do, instead, is to have the conf files in separate directories, one for each provider:

`/etc/openvpn/P1/London.conf`

`/etc/openvpn/P1/Paris.conf`

`/etc/openvpn/P2/London.conf`

`/etc/openvpn/P2/Paris.conf`

If I do like that and then I try to start `systemctl start openvpn@P1/London` or any other variant for other servers, I get an error.

The question is: how can I get what I want?

Comment: As for the preliminary question, I discovered that to have `systemctl` realize that I made a change in the config file I need to launch the command `systemctl daemon-reload`. The main question, instaed, is still open to me.

Answer (score 1):

I achieve this by creating folders for every server that I want to create under `/etc/openvpn/server/`.

In those directories, I keep the `ccd` dir, the `ipp.txt` file and the secrets.

Only the config for each service goes to `/etc/openvpn/server/foo.conf` and then references the config items in the subdir. E.g.

```
ifconfig-pool-persist foo/ipp.txt
```

The service would then be started with `systemctl start openvpn@foo.service`